# Is there a way to extract sentences after bold text in Python?

Tags: python, pdfplumber

I have extracted some bold text from a pdf in python. Which works fine. But I want to extract also the sentence, or more then one sentence after the bold text, e.g. "**Blue sky** is what we see when we look up."

I can extract the blue sky part. But I'm not able to extract the "is what we see when we look up" part.

```
import pdfplumber 

with pdfplumber.open('C:/Users/somefile.pdf') as pdf: 
    for i in range(12, 15):
        text = pdf.pages[i]
        clean_text = text.filter(lambda obj: obj["object_type"] == "char" and "Bold" in obj["fontname"])
        print(clean_text.extract_text())
```

Comment: Try to iterate over `text.chars` and print entry which appears after bold char and until some delimiter

Answer (score 2):

In my answer I will provide the code which uses the approach:

> Try to iterate over text.chars and print entry which appears after bold char and until some delimiter – *Olvin Roght*

With the code below the task of extracting sentences which begin with bold character (or are entire bold) comes down to running:

### get_boldSentences_from(PDFplumberPage)

This function returns a Python list with strings containing all of the text sections in the PDF document which begin with a bold character and end with a period:

```
def get_boldSentences_from(PDFplumberPage):
    #, startsWith='PROP:"bold"', endsWith='CHAR:"."'):
    lstDct = PDFplumberPage.chars
    extracting = False
    lstSentences = []
    strSentence  = None
    for dct in lstDct:
        if not extracting:
            if 'bold'.upper() in dct['fontname'].upper():
                extracting = True
                strSentence = dct['text']
            #:if 'bold'
        else: # extracting:
            char = dct['text'] 
            if  char == ".":
                strSentence += char
                lstSentences.append(strSentence)
                strSentence = ''
                extracting = False
            else:
                strSentence += char
            #:if/else
        #:if/else
    #:for dct in lstDct        
    return lstSentences
#:def

with pdfplumber.open(str_pdf_file, password='') as pdf:
    PDFplumberPage = pdf.pages[0]
    print( get_boldSentences_from(PDFplumberPage) )
```

An interesting approach, but sure hard to grasp for a newbie how it does what it does was posted as a comment to my answer:

> You can apply [certain optimizations](https://tio.run/##dVLLasMwELz7K7Y62cWYQi8lEAolOQRSCm1uaTBOvI7VyJJYyaT5eteSidK89rSaGY9mV9YHWyv5/KKp6ypSDXCLZJUSBnijFVmwxQ73NReYQklK@zaKJtP57H22mH5@wRhY9vDKoqjECrjJpbL5Woky3tQFJaMI@iK0LUlgbx/zCQMuwXFLVilpZdEgW2Wt1khxcuZSouCNC3TDajCw@GvZCnqxMz2FGmy2OCTJDUqLcoMm1sUWE/BGzsH06f0FDs88ksBA@0FhQS0O97o6@riZWfajuIwDd7QMoSpFHnDJwhLP9a4uZ02vFGHt1x//M3CDpjcFfqwrJolun04dr8LAozPxgaMoAxcoFOZCuCYsdgGJ9tzWoMtKi7ZZI2VKo4yNpbzH8sr/YrowZq@oHDOWQGGcerB0D9SvvT9nrjXLp9WAE5c2frz31GkfU4/Zt2RJ1/0B) to your code ;-) – Olvin Roght

After small debugging and further [certain optimizations](https://tio.run/##dVLBasMwDL3nKzSfkhHCYJcRKIPRDgrdCmsuoyvBaZTGa2Ib26Xr12ex0ybLuukkPT0/yZLkyZSC3z9I1TQ5FrBDk2aiylON3CDfovYl3WEQgwetFUrUwAwqI0SlgdVSKAOG7vFYsgpDyJWQznX06Wwxf5kns7cVTIBEN4/Ewc/L12SVvC9mYOGn5WLa4duSKt1CtoArGzkkgK6404VEHTB2sbVLm1aIRJ@Ccb/PXSTXxOCXIRsohHIAMD70POZbq2id5dQx47EAF8a@Hb4VXj3uB3Cte6U9zOEs3BUrBDec1kg20UHKdhRB@KdWN5xRaogGjxX9lOIR@cSwyvtcn8JK/yJmCuneOy9b5oWsDnWGCrwjM@UPIBISua@NSlssLdxBSKr1Uah8QkgAVFt2J273226tjSPr6vXdpsMV48a//e8Qw7ZhOSEfnARe03wD) here the code which has an equivalent function to the code posted above:

```
def get_bold_sentences(page): 
    from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile
    DELIMITERS = ".!?"
    FONTSTYLE  = "BOLD"
    chars = iter(page.chars)  
    while True:
        sentence = "".join(
            char["text"] for char in takewhile(
                lambda char: char["text"] not in DELIMITERS,
                dropwhile(
                    lambda char: FONTSTYLE not in char["fontname"].upper(),
                    chars)
            )
        )
        if sentence:
            yield sentence
        else:
            break
import pdfplumber 
with pdfplumber.open(str_pdf_file, password="") as pdf:
    page = pdf.pages[0]
    print(*get_bold_sentences(page), sep="\n")
```

Notice that the function above is a generator function, so in order to get all of the returned value it is necessary to use `list()` on it. You can see from the print statement the difference. With specification of a separator in call to `print()` the sentences can be printed separated by newline.

Comment: You can apply [certain optimizations](https://tio.run/##dVLLasMwELz7K7Y62cWYQi8lEAolOQRSCm1uaTBOvI7VyJJYyaT5eteSidK89rSaGY9mV9YHWyv5/KKp6ypSDXCLZJUSBnijFVmwxQ73NReYQklK@zaKJtP57H22mH5@wRhY9vDKoqjECrjJpbL5Woky3tQFJaMI@iK0LUlgbx/zCQMuwXFLVilpZdEgW2Wt1khxcuZSouCNC3TDajCw@GvZCnqxMz2FGmy2OCTJDUqLcoMm1sUWE/BGzsH06f0FDs88ksBA@0FhQS0O97o6@riZWfajuIwDd7QMoSpFHnDJwhLP9a4uZ02vFGHt1x//M3CDpjcFfqwrJolun04dr8LAozPxgaMoAxcoFOZCuCYsdgGJ9tzWoMtKi7ZZI2VKo4yNpbzH8sr/YrowZq@oHDOWQGGcerB0D9SvvT9nrjXLp9WAE5c2frz31GkfU4/Zt2RJ1/0B) to your code ;-)

Comment: This one  https://tio.run/##dVLBasMwDL3nKzSfkhHCYJcRKIPRDgrdCmsuoyvBaZTGa2Ib26Xr12ex0ybLuukkPT0/yZLkyZSC3z9I1TQ5FrBDk2aiylON3CDfovYl3WEQgwetFUrUwAwqI0SlgdVSKAOG7vFYsgpDyJWQznX06Wwxf5kns7cVTIBEN4/Ewc/L12SVvC9mYOGn5WLa4duSKt1CtoArGzkkgK6404VEHTB2sbVLm1aIRJ@Ccb/PXSTXxOCXIRsohHIAMD70POZbq2id5dQx47EAF8a@Hb4VXj3uB3Cte6U9zOEs3BUrBDec1kg20UHKdhRB@KdWN5xRaogGjxX9lOIR@cSwyvtcn8JK/yJmCuneOy9b5oWsDnWGCrwjM@UPIBISua@NSlssLdxBSKr1Uah8QkgAVFt2J273226tjSPr6vXdpsMV48a//e8Qw7ZhOSEfnARe03wD  works as expected. Nice approach.